Failed to create the Amazon Opensearch Serverless collection when trying to create AWS Bedrock Knowledge Base
good day.
Trying to create AWS Bedrock Knowledge base with web crawler (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSnFZhHuIgg).
I have already the necessary policies on my user which provided below. But upon creating, I'm encountering a generic error which is "Failed to create the Amazon Opensearch Serverless collection"
I don't know what to do, thus seeking help here, hoping someone could help me
AWS Region: Sydney or singapore
Here is the policy attached to the user

AmazonBedrockFullAccess

custom policies:


A.
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "aoss:CreateAccessPolicy",
                "aoss:CreateSecurityPolicy",
                "aoss:CreateCollection"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

B.
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "aws-marketplace:ViewSubscriptions",
                "aws-marketplace:Unsubscribe",
                "aws-marketplace:Subscribe"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}


can anyone help me please

Login as root user and create a IAM role user with "AdministratorAccess" in policies. Then try to create AWS Bedrock Knowledge Base. It will now give you access to create it

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
